# Subclass calling its superclass method

Tags: python, python-2.7

please I have a class WN that is a subclass of N. N has a method create_nl() that appends the keys and values in the pos dictionary to two empty lists nl and nv. My question is how can I write a method in the subclass to call the create_nl() method in class N such that A and B in wr(), gets assigned random values from the nl list in the superclass method create_nl().I have written a code for that below but it generates an error. Thanks

```
import random as rand

pos = {1:(0, 0.1), 2:(0, 0.), 3:(0, 0.3), 4:(0, 0.4), 5:(0, 0.5), 6:(0, 0.6) }

class N(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def create_nl(self):
        nv = []
        nl = []
        for key, value in pos.iteritems():
            nl.append(key)
            nv.append(value)
        return nl

nn = N("CT")
nn.create_nl()


class WN(N):

def n(self):
    return super(WN, self).create_nl()

def wr(self):

    count = 0

    while count < 1:

        A = int(rand.choice(self.n))
        B = int(rand.choice(self.n))

    count += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call superclass methods directly on subclass instances. You only need to use `super` if you've overridden the method in the subclass and you want to access the superclass version instead of the override.

```
class WN(N):
    def wr(self):
        nl = self.create_nl() # calls superclass method, which we have not overridden

        A = random.choice(nl) # use the return value
        B = random.choice(nl)
```

Note that it's a bit strange to be using a method like `create_nl` to access global data, rather than instance data. Your `random.choice` calls could just as easily be done directly on `pos` directly!